# How can I examine the whole source tree with an annotation processor?

Tags: android, dalvik, annotation-processing

I have a lot of handler classes that handle specific message types.  To register all these handlers, I need to know which ones exist.  Currently, they're all annotated with a specific annotation, and I use a Java 6 annotation processor to get all of them, and make a Register class that holds an instance of each of the annotated types.

This works great if the whole tree is being built at once, but if just one of the annotated classes is being built (when I save the file in Eclipse, for example), the processor only sees that type, and builds an incomplete Register.  How can I examine the other types in this scenario?

Comment: What annotation processor are you using?

Comment: One I wrote myself, using the Java 6 API (extending javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor)

Comment: +1.  From my own investigations this is not available, but if it is I'd really like to know about it.

Comment: Im wondering, does eclipse recompile the entire source tree when it exports the apk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this well enough for now.  What I did is a little hackey, but basically for every annotated class I see, I add its name to a HashSet.  Then I use Filer.getResource() to get open a file where I've recorded all the previously-seen annotated classes, and add those to the HashSet too.  Then I generate the register class, and write the whole HashSet out to the same resource with Filer.createResource().  This will cause problems if I delete an annotated type, since it will still be recorded in that file, but I can just clean the project or delete that file to solve it.

EDIT: Also, I believe that passing the appropriate "originating elements" to Filer.createSource() should allow Eclipse to track those dependencies properly, but it doesn't.  Perhaps that's an Eclipse bug.

Comment: do you happen to have this code shared anywhere?  I'm interested in your approach.

Comment: This is company-owned code, but if I ever write something like this for a personal project it will be available

Comment: I've written a [generic library](https://github.com/sentinelt/evo-classindex) for this. I found this page, because my library suffers from the same problem...

Comment: That's awesome, I always wanted to do this but never had the time.  I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, compile-time annotation processors only process the files being compiled.  Eclipse uses incremental compilation to save time, so the short answer is that you cannot expect your annotation processor to see all types in one pass.

One solution is to change your architecture to support incremental compilation.  For example, for each annotated `HandlerClass`, generate a `RegisterHandlerClass` class that registers that handler class.

That said, sounds like what you are doing would be better done at runtime, perhaps with the help of a tool like [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/).

Comment: This is Android code, and it looks like most of those frameworks don't work on Android; in any case, I'd like to avoid classpath scanning if at all possible.

If I went the RegisterHandlerClass route, how exactly would that help?  How could I get those classes to register the appropriate handler class, without having a "register of registers" so to speak?

Comment: If the problem is that Handler Classes are not being loaded, then my RegisterHandlerClass idea won't work either. You could instead create one resource file per Handler Class and put them all in the same directory and then just scan that directory at runtime.